# Array atribuída em outra não mantém o mesmo valor

Tags: python, array

```py
key=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
x=key
i=0
print(1,key)
while i<4:
    x[0][i]=x[2][i]
    i+=1
print(2,x)
print(3,key) #key era para se manter o mesmo valor, mas quando altera x, key está se alterando também,
```

Eu simplesmente quero atribuir o valor da *array* `key` para `x`, mas sempre que eu altero `x`, `key` também se altera sozinho

No terminal o `print` sai:

```
1 [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
2 [[7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
3 [[7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Se é uma lista composta, possui listas aninhadas, use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

A diferença entre cópia superficial e profunda é relevante apenas para objetos compostos (objetos que contêm outros objetos, como listas ou instâncias de classe):

Uma cópia superficial constrói um novo objeto composto e, em seguida, (na medida do possível) insere referências aos objetos encontrados no original.

Já uma cópia profunda constrói um novo objeto composto e, em seguida, recursivamente, insere cópias dos objetos encontrados no original.

```
import copy

key=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
x= copy.deepcopy(key)
i=0
print(1,key)
while i<4:
    x[0][i]=x[2][i]
    i+=1
print(2,x)
print(3,key)
```

Resultado:

```
1 [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
2 [[7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
3 [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WindingJoyousNanotechnology)

Answer (score 0):

Quando você atribui diretamente `x = key` o que você está passando não o objeto de `key` e sim o endereço de memória, ou seja, o id do objeto. Logo, quando você realiza uma alteração através de `x` você altera `key` pois ambos estão apontando para o mesmo objeto na memória.

```
# Código de exemplo

nomes_registrados = ["joana","leandro","pedro","maria"]
nomes = nomes_registrados
nomes.pop(2)
print(nomes_registrados) # A saída será ['joana', 'leandro', 'maria']
```

Para corrigir o código, utilize o método `copy()`. Esse método cria uma cópia do objeto atual porém com um endereço diferente. Veja como o exemplo acima ficaria:

```
# Código de exemplo

nomes_registrados = ["joana","leandro","pedro","maria"]
nomes = nomes_registrados.copy()
nomes.pop(2)
print(nomes_registrados) # A saída será ['joana', 'leandro', 'pedro', 'maria']
```

O problema é que se você for usar o método `copy`, deverá copiar cada objeto dentro da sua lista, já que sua cópia passada para `x` conteria os endereços de memória de objetos iguais aos de `key` dentro dele.

Então uma outra forma de resolver o seu problema é utilizando a função `copy.deepcopy` do módulo `copy`. Exemplo:

```
# Código de exemplo

import copy
numbers = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
list_2 = copy.deepcopy(numbers)
list_2.pop(1)
print(numbers) # Saída: [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
print(list_2) # Saída: [[1, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Vou atirar algo ao ar mas tecnicamente em Python apontadores nao existem, mas penso que ao fazer isso dessa forma o seu `x` esteja a "apontar" para o mesmo id de objeto que o `key`, ou seja nao criaste uma variável nova simplesmente tem um nome novo que aponta para o mesmo objeto

Tenta fazer o seguinte

```
key=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
x=key.copy()
i=0
print(1,key)
while i<4:
    x[0][i]=x[2][i]
    i+=1
print(2,x)
print(3,key)
```

Ou mesmo

```
 key=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
    x=list(key)
    i=0
    print(1,key)
    while i<4:
        x[0][i]=x[2][i]
        i+=1
    print(2,x)
    print(3,key)
```

Terceira opcao e mais rapida

```
    key=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
    x=key[:]
    i=0
    print(1,key)
    while i<4:
        x[0][i]=x[2][i]
        i+=1
    print(2,x)
    print(3,key)
```

e com deepcopy para nestedLists

```
import copy

key=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
x=copy.deepcopy(key)
i=0
print(1,key)
while i<4:
    x[0][i]=x[2][i]
    i+=1
print(2,x)
print(3,key)
```

Answer (score -1):

Quando você faz essa atribuição:

```
x=key
```

Você não tem duas listas, apenas copia a referência de key para x. Então alteração em qualquer uma das duas referências, afetará somente uma lista, que é a mesma.
Para copiar o conteúdo da string, você pode usar o método copy (disponível desde o Python 3.3):

```
x = key.copy()
```

Ou ainda usar o slice

```
x = key[:]
```

Ou usar o construtor

```
x = list(key)
```